# Maximum distance between any two vertices of a polygon

Tags: python, geometry

I have a list of longitudes and latitudes of vertices of a Polygon. These coordinate are in projected coordinate system and in meters. Distance between any two vertices can be calculated as simple Euclidean distance.
I want to calculate the largest distance between any two vertices which can be referred as diameter of polygon.

```
lis_lat_long = [['1835512.146', '-3239236.854'],
 ['1835395.956', '-3239257.039'],
 ['1835139.106', '-3239366.877'],
 ['1834981.710', '-3239356.042'],
 ['1834938.231', '-3239375.154'],
 ['1834770.578', '-3239540.771'],
 ['1834734.402', '-3239557.223'],
 ['1834438.641', '-3239555.921'],
 ['1834223.286', '-3239586.463'],
 ['1834085.627', '-3239559.935'],
 ['1833968.551', '-3239557.085'],
 ['1833765.725', '-3239632.053'],
 ['1833728.380', '-3239656.957'],
 ['1833728.426', '-3239639.481'],
 ['1833686.217', '-3239533.590'],
 ['1833691.401', '-3239521.642'],
 ['1833644.753', '-3239460.690'],
 ['1833605.786', '-3239455.803'],
 ['1833483.844', '-3239468.720'],
 ['1833449.012', '-3239480.277'],
 ['1833344.883', '-3239595.946'],
 ['1833295.328', '-3239623.781'],
 ['1833166.992', '-3239652.882'],
 ['1833128.570', '-3239672.435'],
 ['1832983.109', '-3239786.355'],
 ['1832939.996', '-3239798.097'],
 ['1832888.462', '-3239795.852'],
 ['1832701.447', '-3239745.817'],
 ['1832592.984', '-3239704.983'],
 ['1832481.850', '-3239610.119'],
 ['1832419.197', '-3239530.270'],
 ['1832372.714', '-3239511.904'],
 ['1832218.735', '-3239291.581'],
 ['1832063.013', '-3239183.406'],
 ['1831951.167', '-3239132.681'],
 ['1831863.114', '-3239111.652'],
 ['1831744.389', '-3239107.381'],
 ['1831701.505', '-3239096.349'],
 ['1831637.554', '-3239046.953'],
 ['1831553.772', '-3239016.069'],
 ['1831441.089', '-3238992.231'],
 ['1831358.195', '-3238955.454'],
 ['1831104.618', '-3238809.221'],
 ['1831064.761', '-3238778.801'],
 ['1831040.021', '-3238695.083'],
 ['1831009.800', '-3238640.200'],
 ['1830984.046', '-3238618.579'],
 ['1830813.824', '-3238552.980'],
 ['1830737.693', '-3238506.874'],
 ['1830684.415', '-3238469.741'],
 ['1830576.412', '-3238346.902'],
 ['1830524.522', '-3238321.013'],
 ['1830452.078', '-3238336.643'],
 ['1830368.231', '-3238395.289'],
 ['1830282.442', '-3238503.561'],
 ['1830244.647', '-3238505.171'],
 ['1830224.131', '-3238475.403'],
 ['1830224.533', '-3238407.833'],
 ['1830214.603', '-3238369.477'],
 ['1830175.525', '-3238325.177'],
 ['1830158.692', '-3238324.743'],
 ['1830061.388', '-3238361.880'],
 ['1830011.852', '-3238328.626'],
 ['1829964.991', '-3238251.386'],
 ['1829920.391', '-3238136.856'],
 ['1829936.304', '-3238067.307'],
 ['1829970.006', '-3238014.828'],
 ['1829969.739', '-3237985.122'],
 ['1829934.065', '-3237892.636'],
 ['1829928.018', '-3237808.819'],
 ['1829911.678', '-3237759.867'],
 ['1829890.037', '-3237746.091'],
 ['1829826.524', '-3237732.756'],
 ['1829739.089', '-3237746.368'],
 ['1829633.080', '-3237680.587'],
 ['1829558.529', '-3237686.734'],
 ['1829516.868', '-3237668.724'],
 ['1829464.967', '-3237659.687'],
 ['1829364.924', '-3237615.948'],
 ['1829312.409', '-3237605.049'],
 ['1829280.061', '-3237569.848'],
 ['1829273.684', '-3237522.288'],
 ['1829290.245', '-3237468.112'],
 ['1829353.217', '-3237397.127'],
 ['1829329.545', '-3237247.234'],
 ['1829308.104', '-3237209.801'],
 ['1829289.443', '-3237204.445'],
 ['1829235.164', '-3237217.078'],
 ['1829100.663', '-3237152.101'],
 ['1829067.738', '-3237177.139'],
 ['1829062.856', '-3237221.343'],
 ['1829046.186', '-3237248.053'],
 ['1829019.402', '-3237251.989'],
 ['1828985.913', '-3237232.224'],
 ['1828968.381', '-3237233.790'],
 ['1828922.173', '-3237282.727'],
 ['1828901.318', '-3237289.327'],
 ['1828844.121', '-3237182.202'],
 ['1828822.191', '-3237165.064'],
 ['1828733.547', '-3237121.718'],
 ['1828685.036', '-3237115.742'],
 ['1828632.013', '-3237071.453'],
 ['1828566.550', '-3237048.093'],
 ['1828545.802', '-3237045.412'],
 ['1828508.815', '-3237063.973'],
 ['1828481.129', '-3237059.472'],
 ['1828464.959', '-3237113.708'],
 ['1828440.386', '-3237137.125'],
 ['1828397.567', '-3237154.366'],
 ['1828388.351', '-3237190.611'],
 ['1828390.286', '-3237228.979'],
 ['1828381.847', '-3237237.118'],
 ['1828339.253', '-3237216.758'],
 ['1828323.458', '-3237231.757'],
 ['1828317.185', '-3237245.201'],
 ['1828320.478', '-3237296.834'],
 ['1828268.860', '-3237299.688'],
 ['1828212.770', '-3237324.341'],
 ['1828185.908', '-3237320.297'],
 ['1828170.340', '-3237331.124'],
 ['1828155.782', '-3237329.375'],
 ['1828139.314', '-3237312.064'],
 ['1828110.533', '-3237306.958'],
 ['1828031.357', '-3237316.290'],
 ['1828016.624', '-3237330.122'],
 ['1828014.854', '-3237386.527'],
 ['1828002.702', '-3237400.303'],
 ['1827956.965', '-3237429.061'],
 ['1827851.667', '-3237460.252'],
 ['1827827.078', '-3237531.042'],
 ['1827839.289', '-3237647.549'],
 ['1827833.156', '-3237683.042'],
 ['1827790.529', '-3237741.707'],
 ['1827786.734', '-3237766.926'],
 ['1827749.508', '-3237804.159'],
 ['1827733.895', '-3237854.717'],
 ['1827647.598', '-3237922.528'],
 ['1827587.042', '-3237923.707'],
 ['1827564.401', '-3237947.419'],
 ['1827519.506', '-3237939.776'],
 ['1827487.033', '-3237944.741'],
 ['1827458.030', '-3237980.555'],
 ['1827458.774', '-3238006.455'],
 ['1827425.864', '-3238085.291'],
 ['1827418.256', '-3238127.313'],
 ['1827370.535', '-3238181.120'],
 ['1827362.571', '-3238234.045'],
 ['1827464.503', '-3238387.963'],
 ['1827462.060', '-3238463.967'],
 ['1827450.127', '-3238500.580'],
 ['1827455.408', '-3238570.553'],
 ['1827471.556', '-3238612.939'],
 ['1827385.809', '-3238740.163'],
 ['1827154.723', '-3238948.119'],
 ['1827140.742', '-3238937.272'],
 ['1827041.048', '-3238774.397'],
 ['1826971.637', '-3238687.358'],
 ['1826948.507', '-3238705.794'],
 ['1826873.362', '-3238687.737'],
 ['1826807.692', '-3238547.581'],
 ['1826768.755', '-3238420.857'],
 ['1826720.026', '-3238351.323'],
 ['1826554.765', '-3238062.593'],
 ['1826533.565', '-3237991.997'],
 ['1826533.341', '-3237919.246'],
 ['1826549.338', '-3237849.706'],
 ['1826670.287', '-3237642.105'],
 ['1826683.334', '-3237592.821'],
 ['1826663.727', '-3237543.163'],
 ['1826518.674', '-3237382.105'],
 ['1826494.123', '-3237342.331'],
 ['1826459.375', '-3237177.832'],
 ['1826495.472', '-3237098.144'],
 ['1826638.764', '-3236976.583'],
 ['1826668.729', '-3236924.532'],
 ['1826682.421', '-3236875.566'],
 ['1826713.483', '-3236841.167'],
 ['1826745.591', '-3236781.467'],
 ['1826803.185', '-3236606.174'],
 ['1826803.564', '-3236539.269'],
 ['1826773.001', '-3236448.782'],
 ['1826783.082', '-3236377.800'],
 ['1826854.642', '-3236308.761'],
 ['1826890.009', '-3236214.909'],
 ['1826936.445', '-3236180.167'],
 ['1827024.431', '-3236158.317'],
 ['1827181.609', '-3236075.927'],
 ['1827240.471', '-3236011.178'],
 ['1827262.000', '-3235956.751'],
 ['1827307.430', '-3235920.862'],
 ['1827437.089', '-3235874.290'],
 ['1827477.981', '-3235883.653'],
 ['1827541.025', '-3235932.987'],
 ['1827590.248', '-3235930.321'],
 ['1827711.630', '-3235875.094'],
 ['1827820.787', '-3235850.455'],
 ['1827849.646', '-3235818.936'],
 ['1827854.711', '-3235786.603'],
 ['1827836.023', '-3235736.750'],
 ['1827787.182', '-3235661.330'],
 ['1827771.854', '-3235604.897'],
 ['1827782.069', '-3235536.372'],
 ['1827817.103', '-3235482.207'],
 ['1827868.764', '-3235457.440'],
 ['1827910.952', '-3235413.539'],
 ['1827925.603', '-3235431.132'],
 ['1828032.472', '-3235482.082'],
 ['1828137.470', '-3235550.901'],
 ['1828309.129', '-3235699.485'],
 ['1828437.541', '-3235740.624'],
 ['1828488.964', '-3235867.237'],
 ['1828626.377', '-3235914.275'],
 ['1828676.868', '-3235913.796'],
 ['1828795.362', '-3236009.669'],
 ['1828827.106', '-3236056.179'],
 ['1828877.598', '-3236062.785'],
 ['1828938.744', '-3236124.571'],
 ['1829038.557', '-3236158.748'],
 ['1829168.368', '-3236164.570'],
 ['1829317.950', '-3236079.513'],
 ['1829492.278', '-3236025.856'],
 ['1829553.371', '-3235979.519'],
 ['1829569.386', '-3235781.598'],
 ['1829763.275', '-3235681.137'],
 ['1829985.907', '-3234978.341'],
 ['1830084.642', '-3234991.598'],
 ['1830103.115', '-3235032.348'],
 ['1830147.224', '-3235039.088'],
 ['1830199.403', '-3234995.161'],
 ['1830189.149', '-3234940.523'],
 ['1830191.556', '-3234859.155'],
 ['1830287.759', '-3234824.355'],
 ['1830337.464', '-3234915.375'],
 ['1830611.541', '-3234991.131'],
 ['1833425.390', '-3238626.813'],
 ['1833361.604', '-3238824.512'],
 ['1833606.583', '-3238583.326'],
 ['1833976.391', '-3238589.144'],
 ['1834240.904', '-3238477.109'],
 ['1834349.419', '-3238460.625'],
 ['1834560.042', '-3238491.230'],
 ['1834616.158', '-3238528.161'],
 ['1834734.615', '-3238647.457'],
 ['1834951.986', '-3238938.772'],
 ['1835039.258', '-3239002.100'],
 ['1835113.411', '-3239029.358'],
 ['1835225.012', '-3239037.149'],
 ['1835337.586', '-3239076.191'],
 ['1835438.778', '-3239179.715'],
 ['1835512.146', '-3239236.854']]
```

Comment: Then they are not longitudes and latitudes. You can call them X and Y or easting and northing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this amount of data points (~ 200), we can build simple `for-loop` covering all pairs of vertices and calculating the distance for every pair. If this distance is above the current maximum, it becomes the current maximum.

Moreover, your distances are stored as strings and need to be converted to floats.

I used `numpy` for both conversion and calculation of Euclidean distance.

Edit after @aerobiomat 's comment suggesting the use of `itertools.combinations` over `itertools.product`

```py
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

lis_lat_long = np.array(lis_lat_long, float)

current_max = 0
for a, b in combinations(np.array(lis_lat_long), 2):
    current_distance = np.linalg.norm(a-b)
    if current_distance > current_max:
       current_max = current_distance
```

Comment: itertools.product() generates n*n pairs, containing repeated comparisons, including a point with itself. For 200 points that's 40000 pairs.
Instead, itertools.combinations() generates the minimum required: n*(n-1)/2 pairs. For 200 points that's 19900 pairs.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of posts on using numpy and its einsum function to determine distances.
First, your string data needs to be converted to float, then a little einsum magic.

```
a = np.array(lis_lat_long).astype('float')

a0 = a[:, None]

diff = a - a0

dist_arr = np.sqrt(np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ij', diff, diff))

np.max(dist_arr)
Out[42]: 9283.977292891426
```

timing for this
1.52 ms ± 18.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
timing for accepted
213 ms ± 14.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
from itertools import combinations
import math

def calc_dist(p1, p2):
    x1 = p1[0] - p2[0]
    y1 = p1[1] - p2[1]
    return math.sqrt(pow(x1, 2) + pow(y1, 2))


def diameter(data):
    data = [list(map(float, c)) for c in data]
    combs = list(combinations(data, 2))
    print(max([calc_dist(*points) for points in combs]))
```

Returns 9283.977292891426 for your data